# Telethon sending of messages gets stuck for a while then continues

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

i am try to send messages to the groups that i have joined using telethon. everything works fine but most of the times, it gets stuck for about 1min-1min 30s then it continues. this issue occurs multiple times during the process. also its really slow. please help

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, utils
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
import asyncio

api_id = xxxxxx
api_hash = 'hash54356'

client = TelegramClient('new_session', api_id, api_hash, system_version="4.16.30-vxITSNOTBOT")

# Define a function to send a message
async def send_message(target, messages):
    try:
        if not str(target).startswith("-100"):
            print(f"{target} is not a valid group. Skipping...")
            return
        for message in messages:
            await client.send_message(target, message)
        print(f"Sent {len(messages)} messages to {target}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while sending the message to the group {target}: {e}")


# Define the main function that calls the send_message function
async def main():
    # Get all the dialogs (chats) that you are a member of
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        # Check if the dialog is a group chat
        if dialog.is_group:
            # Get the ID of the group chat
            target = dialog.id
            # Send the message to the group chat
            messages = ["https://t.me/channel1", "https://t.me/channel2"]
            await send_message(target, messages)


# Run the main function using the client's event loop
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely experiencing flood waits. The [`TelegramClient`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon-client) currently has a default `flood_sleep_threshold` of one minute.

You can set this to 0 if you want to handle all errors yourself:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, errors

client = TelegramClient(..., flood_sleep_threshold=0)

try:
    await client.send_message(...)
except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
    print('flood for', e.seconds)
```

You can set it to a higher number if you want even less of those to occur (the library will simply sleep for as long as needed):

```py
client = TelegramClient(..., flood_sleep_threshold=24 * 60 * 60)
```

And you can enable `logging` if you want to learn when the sleeps happen:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
```